OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when vector_store retriever is invoked
I'm in the midst of developing Genai app with

private data stored in vertex ai vector db
llm as gpt4
langhain as orchestrator

When I invoke vector_store retriever I get error:

OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.

The vector store index is being created with same credentials.
Here is sample code:
aiplatform.init(credentials=credentials, project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION, staging_bucket=BUCKET_URI)
my_index = aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndex.list()[0]
my_index_endpoint = aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndexEndpoint.list()[0]
embedding_model = VertexAIEmbeddings(model_name="textembedding-gecko@003")
vector_store = VectorSearchVectorStore.from_components(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    gcs_bucket_name=BUCKET,
    index_id=my_index.name,
    endpoint_id=my_index_endpoint.name,
    embedding=embedding_model,
)

# Initialize the vectore_store as retriever
retriever = vector_store.as_retriever()
# perform simple similarity search on retriever
result = retriever.invoke("What are my options in breathable fabric?") #<<<<<ERROR here

google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:34.128.134.161:443: Ssl handshake failed (TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE): SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED


503 Error means it didn't even try to connect, the format is incorrect somewhere.   You should of at least got a 400 type if the SSL was correct enough to make an attempt to connect.  Can you use something to verify that the SSL you are using is valid?

It is also possible it expired, you can try this format to test it :
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourwebsite.com:443
